# WCF Service doesn't return data

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin

I want to create simple mobile add using Xamarin which uses a WCF Service, but I have a problem with returning data from the database.

Firstly I connect to a SQL Server database with WCF and create code:

**IServiceWhitewagon:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceWhitewagon
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<CompanyForView> GetCompany();
}
```

**ServiceWhitewagon**

```
public class ServiceWhitewagon : IServiceWhitewagon
{
   public ServiceWhitewagon()
   {
   }

   public List<CompanyForView> GetCompany()
   {
       WhitewagonEntities db = new WhitewagonEntities();
       return
           (from company in db.Company
            select new CompanyForView
            {
                idCompany = company.idCompany,
                name = company.name,
                phone = company.phone,
                adress = company.adress
            }
            ).ToList();
   }
}
```

**CompanyForView**

```
[DataContract]
public class CompanyForView
{
    [DataMember]
    public int idCompany { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string adress { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

In the next step, I connect WCF with my app called `AppMobileWhitewagon`:

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prgun.png)

While connecting to WCF, I am using `http://localhost:54308/` and I saw all created methods in WCF. What's more I test WCF with the WCF Test Client and I see data from the database table:

[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOLYI.png)

In my MobileApp, I have problem with showing data from the database. When in app I click on the button who should show card with data from the database, the app freezes on 20 seconds and shows an empty card.

My code in class which should get data:

```
public class CompanyDataStore : ItemDataStore<Company>
{
    public CompanyDataStore()
    {
        items = zamowieniaServices.GetCompany(null).GetCompanyResult.Select(k => new Company
        {
            idCompany = k.idCompany,
            name = k.name,
            phone = k.phone,
            adress = k.adress
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**ItemDataStore**

```
public abstract class ItemDataStore<T> : IDataStore<T>
{
    public List<T> items;

    public IServiceWhitewagon zamowieniaServices { get; set; }

    public ItemDataStore()
    {
        zamowieniaServices = DependencyService.Get<ServiceReferenceWhitewagon.IServiceWhitewagon>();
    }
}
```

I create 3 breakpoints in app:

[Screen3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jlPO.png)

App stops at the first breakpoint, and when I continue to run, the code does not get to the next breakpoint.

**PS 1**: I suppose that with my view every thing is ok, since when I change code in `CompanyDataStore` to this, app show data from this list

```
items = new List<Company>()
        {
           new Company{idCompany=1,name="Klient 1"},
           new Company{idCompany=2,name="Klient 2"},
        };
```

**PS 2**: I try turn off WCF and run App, i got this same problem - empty app card without any error

Comment: you will save yourself an immense amount of trouble and headaches if you use RESTful services instead of WCF.  WCF is fairly outdated technology and many better/easier options exist.

Comment: I would like to but I can't because my college lecturer insisted that it must be using WCF :/

Comment: @Jason I disagree; REST is way more of a pain in the ass than WCF. Properly set up WCF client integration is "click, click, paste URL, and it's done"; autorest is still playing catchup with swagger versions and dreams of one day being the same plug n play WCF is.

Comment: @AdrianWróbel i don't know if there's enough info to answer your Q ; the WCF service works because if it didn't the test client would get nothing. You haven't given much detail on what the mobile app is doing, how it connects, if it's an emulator on the same machine, how the networking setup looks. Take the WCF test client to the same context (eg if your mobile app is on a phone on the network and your machine is thus a remote server, put th test client on another machine, get it working..)

Comment: I am using VS's built-in Pixel 2 emulator on the same computer where I am writing the application. I added WCF using the configurator in Connected Services.

Comment: there are about 5 different steps in that compound statement.  Try breaking it up into individual lines to better see what is happening

Comment: Do you call the WCF service by adding a service reference? If you call the WCF service by adding a service reference, the List will be converted to an array by default. I suspect this may be the cause of this problem.

Comment: I try this and i get this same result, i got blank card without any data. It is other way to 
checking that the connection with WCF is ok?

Comment: I have to determine whether this is a WCF issue or a Xamarin issue. Will you receive data if you use another application to call the WCF service?

Comment: You can also try to use the channel factory to call the service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory